# How to messengers receive notification messages from servers?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, message

Currently I am working on an alert app, which receives push notifications from a server. Reading a lot about that topic on the internet lead me to firebase which can be used to achieve that.

Now I was wondering: Are Whatsapp, Signal and other messengers using firebase or do they have any other solution to receive messages from servers even if the app is not active opened?

Answer (score 0):

They use push messaging.  It might be firebase, it might be another provider. MQTT is popular. All any of those things do is open up a persistent socket connection to a server and listen for messages.  The trick is that whatever process is doing that needs to be whitelisted from power management restrictions, because you don't want to delay your message notifications for 15 minutes.

Now if you're writing something that's supposed to be robust queueing on the server side and deduping on the client side would be a good idea.  But the basics is open socket connection and block on it on a thread.